# Css force child div out of parent that has position absolute and overflow hidden

Tags: html, css, position, overflow

I have an expanding DIV animation: http://codepen.io/gabrielmalinosqui/pen/OyLogq

What I now want to do is to add an  list inside the the div with a class of "content" The only problem is if my list is too long it will get clipped since the parrent div has a position absolute and a overflow set to hidden.

So is there any way to force a child div out of the parent even if the parent has a `position:absolute` and `overflow:hidden`

If I swap out my  list to a none-styled  it will work, the select wont get clipped, but that might be some browser styling?

html:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='content'>
    <h2>Well Hello!</h2>
    <p>contents...</p>
  </div>
</div>
<a class='button glyphicon glyphicon-plus' href='#'></a>
```

css:

```
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 85px;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.wrap .content {
  opacity: 0;
}
.wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 95%;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.wrap.active {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 16px silver;
  transition: all 600ms;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.wrap.active:before {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 2000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1000px;
  margin-top: -1000px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}
.wrap.active .content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}
```

Comment: No, that can't be done, so why does the parent have to be absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-y: scroll` to your `.wrap {  }` class

```
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll; //Add this
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 85px;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
```

}